# How do these hijacking ads work (creates unwanted ads on a webpage)

Tags: javascript, html, ads

We are having ads pop up on our webpage, at random times... from links that didn't exist before, i.e. some random text on the page(which wasn't a hyperlink) becomes a Javascript-y link-ad.

[image]

It's the ultimate UI-fail... I find this fascinating - and want to know how this happens.

A friend just told me it's " spyware on your machine. Try cleaning up all cookies. "

Is that so? Like always?

Comment: Have you run a virus scan? Have you inspected the DOM with whatever developer tools your browser has?

Comment: @StephenP it can also happen when someone is given ad space, and then abuses it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would guess they are injecting javascript into a form somewhere on your website.  When the user views a page where the entered data is displayed, the javascript runs, showing the adds.

View the source of the page; do you see a script tag that points to a domain that is not yours?

If it turns out to be a XSS, you need to sanitize the data before it gets presented to the user (among other things).  [Here is a good starting](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) place.

Comment: Cool. So, @Adel ... you've got to sanitize your output to prevent cross site scripting (XSS) attacks.

Comment: @StephenP - OK, so this is a  cross site scripting attack.. and it can be prevented without alot of hassle?

Comment: Nice answer (upvoted) -- however, I sanitize the data as it comes *out* of the database, because I have to store *exactly* what the user typed, partly because I have to escape it in different ways depending on its destination.